# Magento getAttributeName / Text

Tags: magento, attributes

I'm playing arround with magento product attributes.

What i'm trying to do is getting an "Unique Product Number" attached to the same " Unique Video Number" That works perfectly.

The same goes for an Dropdown Attribute using the following code.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/avembed.js"></script>
<div class="av_videoplayer" data-av-search-ean="<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('DropDown_Atribute') ?>"></div>
```

But as soon as i try it with an TextBox or TextField it fails to return an output.
I have been using getAttributeName to make it happen but i can't seem to get it working or find the anwser to do this.

Any tips on what i might be doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where you added this code???

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides magic getters and setters, so for most product attributes, you can retrieve them using the attribute name, preceded by `get`. For example:

```
$freeShipping = $_product->getFreeShipping();
```

The alternative to this is the method you are using, `getAttributeText`.

```
$freeShipping = $_product->getAttributeText('free_shipping');
```

HOWEVER, the attribute must be in the product collection, which most custom attributes are not. When you setup your attribute, you need to set the option `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` to **Yes**.

Failing that, you can recreate the product collection (in your own helper, for example) and add your attribute(s) manually as follows:

```
public function getMyProductCollection( $skuArray ) {
    $products = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(
            array(
                'free_shipping',
                'list_price',
                'manufacturer',
                'name',
                'price',
                'special_price',
                'special_from_date',
                'special_to_date',
                'thumbnail'
            )
        )
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            'sku', array( 'in' => $skuArray )
        )
        ->load();
    return $products;
}
```

You can then use the public function as follows:

```
$_productObj = $this->helper('my_helper')->getMyProductCollection(
    $_productSkus
);
```

Understand that I'm describing the principle, this code is not copy + pastable. Hope that helps.